# Pyspark: Comparing Datasets and Identify Unchanged Records

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, null, anti-join

I am trying to implement a generic historization procedure for my data in PySpark. Those data have a key, several business information columns, and some additional technical metadata, which should not be considered for identifying changes, but should be saved, whenever a change was identified (for example the exact timestamp, when a record has been read). 
The new data arrive in a spark dataframe, and I have also loaded the existing data into a spark dataframe already. So for example

```
old = spark.createDataFrame([("foo", 'f', 1), ('bar', 'b', 1), ('', None, 1)], ['text','first_character','version'])
new = spark.createDataFrame([("foo", 'f', 2), ('Bar', 'B', 2), ('', None, 2)], ['text','first_character','version']) 

old.show()
new.show()
```

The sample shows records with a text column (which is considered to be the key column), an information column showing the first character of the text, and my technical metadata is simplified in the column "version".

```
+----+---------------+-------+
|text|first_character|version|
+----+---------------+-------+
| foo|              f|      1|
| bar|              b|      1|
|    |           null|      1|
+----+---------------+-------+

+----+---------------+-------+
|text|first_character|version|
+----+---------------+-------+
| foo|              f|      2|
| Bar|              B|      2|
|    |           null|      2|
+----+---------------+-------+
```

Now I am looking for the unchanged records.
As you can see, If we ignore the version column, the first record is unchanged, in the second record, the case of the first character was changed to upper, and the third records is also unchanged.

My first idea was to use an anti-join to get the unchanged records:

```
new.join(old, ['text', 'first_character'], "left_anti").show()
```

however this results in

```
+----+---------------+-------+
|text|first_character|version|
+----+---------------+-------+
|    |           null|      2|
| Bar|              B|      2|
+----+---------------+-------+
```

The reason is clear, the comparison of the null values for the records with blank text (which are present in both versions), does not return "equal" but "unknown".

I have a workaround for this problem:

```
new.select('text','first_character')\
   .exceptAll(old.select('text','first_character'))\
   .join(new.select('text','version'), 'text','inner')\
   .show()
```

Which returns the expected result:

```
+----+---------------+-------+
|text|first_character|version|
+----+---------------+-------+
| Bar|              B|      2|
+----+---------------+-------+
```

**My question is:** is there an option to make anti-joins consider two null values as equal, or is there a simpler workaround than mine?

Comment: You can use Null safe Operator ('<=>') 
Doc Link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-null-semantics.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20compare%20the%20NULL%20values%20for,when%20one%20or%20both%20operands%20are%20NULL%60%3A%20Examples

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately it does not really help in my case, because I would need the solution in a generic function, where the number of columns is not fixed (only my sample has only two columns to be compared). So for the moment I am still using my exceptAll approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [.eqNullSafe()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html)

```
new.join(old,
         (new.text.eqNullSafe(old.text)) &
         (new.first_character.eqNullSafe(old.first_character)),
         "left_anti") \
    .show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it does not really help in my case, because I would need the solution in a generic function, where the number of columns is not fixed (only my sample has only two columns to be compared). So for the moment I am still using my exceptAll approach.